# How to filter a ListView using a SearchBar from the Code Behind (MVVM)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView that you want to filter with a SearchBar

[image: gui]

Currently the List is filled from the constructor (parameter step) of my ViewModel as follows

//AGREGAR SUSTANCIA VIEW MODEL

```
    List<AgregarSustancia> listaSustanciasAux;

     ObservableCollection<AgregarSustancia> listaSustancias;

      public ObservableCollection<AgregarSustancia> ListaSustancias
      {
           get
           {
              return listaSustancias;
           }
           set
           {
             if (listaSustancias != value)
             {
                  listaSustancias = value;
                   PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ListaSustancias)));
             }
          }
        }

         public AgregarSustanciaViewModel(ObservableCollection<AgregarSustancia> listaAgregarSustancia)
         {

               ListaSustancias = new ObservableCollection<AgregarSustancia>();
               listaSustanciasAux = new List<AgregarSustancia>();

               listaSustanciasAux = listaAgregarSustancia.ToList();
               ListaSustancias = listaAgregarSustancia;
         }

public ICommand SearchCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand(Search);
            }
        }

        void Search()
        {

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Filter))
                {
                    ListaSustancias = new ObservableCollection<AgregarSustancia>(listaSustanciasAux.OrderBy(o => o.NombreSustancia).OrderByDescending(r => r.IdSustancia));
                }
                else
                {
                    ListaSustancias = new ObservableCollection<AgregarSustancia>(listaSustanciasAux.Where(c => c.IdSustancia.ToString().ToLower().
                                       Contains(Filter.ToLower()) || c.NombreSustancia.ToLower().RemoveDiacritics().Contains(Filter.ToLower())).OrderByDescending(r => r.IdSustancia));
                }

        }
```

As you can see, I manage two lists with the goal that the List binded to the ListView be updated as text is entered into the SearchBar.

The problem is that I cannot do this from my ViewModel since each element of the list has a command (on the Switch) that is executed every time I enter a character in the SearchBar, that is why I have decided to implement the search in the Code behind as follows

//AGREGAR SUSTANCIAS VIEW

```
 <SearchBar
         x:Name="searchBar"
         TextChanged="SearchBar_TextChanged">
 </SearchBar>

      <ListView
                    x:Name="listView"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ListaSustancias}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSustancia}">                      
                     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                                 VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                                 Padding="16,5,0,5">

                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

                                          <Label Text="{Binding NombreSustancia}" 
                                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                               FontSize="Small" 
                                               TextColor="{StaticResource das.color.texto}"
                                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

                                    </StackLayout>

                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

//CODE BEHIND

```
    public AgregarSustanciaView()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }

   private void SearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
   {
     var search = sender as SearchBar;
   }
```

As seen in the following figure, I am capturing the text that is entered in the SearchBar

[image: value]

But how can I access my list and then filter it by linq? How can I access from my code behind my Bindated List of the ViewModel?

How can I filter the list as characters are entered in the SearchBar? 
Any help for me?

Comment: your code behind should have a reference to your VM.  Just create a method in your VM to filter and call it from your code-behind.

Comment: I have edited my question, adding the method that filters the list from the ViewModel, but how can I call it from code behind?

How do I make the reference you indicate? Any help for me? @Jason

Comment: how are you creating your VM?

Comment: @CristofherAmbiado Hi , you can refer to [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-searchbardemos/) to check where problem is .

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you must add behaviours to your project.
https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/creating

Then, you can use like this:

```
<SearchBar>
            <SearchBar.Behaviors>
                <behaviour:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="TextChanged" Command=" {Binding TextChangedCommand}" />
            </SearchBar.Behaviors>
</SearchBar>



  public ICommand TextChangedCommand => new Command((o) =>
        {
            if (o is TextChangedEventArgs text)
            {
            //do some works
            }
        });
```

Also you can use  SearchCommand if you don't want to use behaviours.

```
<SearchBar x:Name="searchBar"   
                       SearchCommand="{Binding MyFilterCommand}"
                       SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference searchBar}}"/>
```

Comment: When Filtering the List as follows, my application is dropped, the CAST Applied Within the command does not work, Some help of How to USE THE "O" parameter   ListaSustancias = new ObservableCollection<AgregarSustancia>(listaSustanciasAux.Where(c => c.IdSustancia.ToString().ToLower().
                                       Contains(((string)o).ToLower()) || c.NombreSustancia.ToLower().RemoveDiacritics().Contains(((string)o).ToLower())).OrderByDescending(r => r.IdSustancia));

Comment: `o.NewTextValue` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.textchangedeventargs?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: @Cristofher Ambiado I answered your question above. You must cast the 'O' parameter.
This is a way of casting:
if (o is TextChangedEventArgs text)
now you  can use 'text' as casted o.